# How to make character amount counter input specific?

Tags: jquery, html

I made this with `jQuery`: it counts the amount of characters in an input field.
Problem: I have two input fields with two counters and they both listen to the first input field... so I can't use them separately. How can I achieve it?

```
var maxLength = 100;
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var length = maxLength-length;
  $('.chars').text(length);
});

 <input type="text" name="title" id="title" maxlength="100">
 <input type="text" name="title" id="title" maxlength="100">
```

Maybe I'll have 5 input fields, even... on one page. I want all counters to work for a specific input field only (just one input field per counter).

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with the same `id` attribute.

Comment: "they both listen to the first input field" ...no they don't. `$(this)` in your keyup handler refers to the field that triggered the keyup event.   They're both writing to the same *output* (`$('.chars')`) but I'm not sure from your question whether that's intentional.

Comment: How you can use same same ID for two attributes?

Comment: @DanielBeck: no, that's not intentional. How can I make it generic so that I can have one counter per input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('input')` matches all input fields, and within the `keyup` handler `this` refers to the specific input that triggered the handler. So far, so good.

The output needs to go to a different node for each input as well. There are many ways to do this; here I've chosen the simple one of "traverse the DOM to the next '.chars' element after the current input":

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength"); // note we can read this from the input, no need for a global variable
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var remaining = maxLength-length;
  $(this).next('.chars').text(remaining)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="100"></input>
<span class="chars"></span>
<br>
 
<input type="text" maxlength="100"></input>
<span class="chars"></span>
```

DOM traversal isn't always a great way to match up elements, though, since editing the HTML layout can end up changing the paths between elements, which will break your script.

Another way to do it would be to put a data- attribute on each `input` and `.chars` node, and use that value to identify which output node corresponds to which input:

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
  var remaining = maxLength-length;
  var myId = $(this).data("counterid");
  $('.chars[data-counterid='+myId+']')
      .text(remaining)
      .toggleClass("full", (remaining===0)); // colors per comment below
});
```

```css
.full {background-color: #FCC}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="10" data-counterid="1"></input>
<span class="chars" data-counterid="1"></span>
<br>
 
<input type="text" maxlength="10" data-counterid="2"></input>
<span class="chars" data-counterid="2"></span>
```

And, yes, as several people have pointed out, IDs should be unique.  This isn't at all relevant to your question, but it's worth fixing anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! I appreciate it. What I see, though... is that if I put the element with the classname "chars" inside a wrapping div, it suddenly doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: Heh -- I'm pretty sure you posted that while I was updating the answer to point out exactly that danger...

Comment: Thank you! It does break something else as well. I was checking the length so that I can give it a red color when it gets close to zero. On what should I do the check now? Because length is broken...

Comment: Oops, yeah, I failed to catch that you were redeclaring `var length` twice in the same function.  I fixed that, and included the coloring when it runs out of space.

Comment: your code gets stuck, eventually when typing. Try it out. When I type in some things in the input fields, it eventually fails to write more (even though I have remaining characters) and even backspace doesn't work properly anymore...

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that. I changed the maxlength to a small value in the second example, to make it easier to see the color change; is that what you mean?

Comment: No. When I try your second example, I can type in some numbers or letters. I have to manually press the input field everytime I want to type down a character. It seems like it loses focus after first keypress...

Comment: ...I'm really not seeing that happen, there's nothing here that should be blurring the field.  Are you seeing this happen in the snippet here, or when you copy it into your own code?

Comment: Both! In the snippet and in my code. Interesting, really. When I try to code before you edited your last snippet, that just works really well. Very very weird. Could you tell me one thing: how can I make if (length < 0)... to be specific for the counter as well? Now, it makes all counters red, while I want the specific counter to be red.

Comment: ...it doesn't make all the counters red. Just the specific one referenced by `$(this)`.  I have a feeling something got garbled in the process of copying the code from this answer to your work.

Comment: No no.. I use it differently. I use this:

if (length < 0)... but clearly, length isn't the one I need to use.

Comment: Length is never less than zero.

Comment: Yeah. I accepted your answer anyway. I'll fix the counter thingie. Thanks, Daniel! Appreciate the help

Answer (score -1):

Your code has the following mistakes:

- `$('input')` will target only the first input field
- The two input fields can't be distinguished since both of them have the same ID `title`
- `$('.chars')` will display the length of one input field. What about the length the other input field?

Here's the piece of code which should achieve what you want to do:

```
var maxLength = 100;

// target #title1
$('#title1').keyup(function() {
  // store length of #title1 in variable length1
  var length1 = $(this).val().length;
  var length1 = maxLength - length1;
  // display length1 in span with class chars1
  $('.chars1').text(length1);
});

// target #title2
$('#title2').keyup(function() {
  // store length of #title2 in variable length2
  var length2 = $(this).val().length;
  var length2 = maxLength - length2;
  // display length2 in span with class chars2
  $('.chars2').text(length2);
});

<input type="text" name="title" id="title1" maxlength="100">
<input type="text" name="title" id="title2" maxlength="100">

<p>Length 1: <span class="chars1"></span></p>
<p>Length 2: <span class="chars2"></span></p>
```

Even though the comments are self-explanatory, let me know if you need help with anything else.

Comment: " $('input') will target only the first input field" => I don't think this is true as it targets ALL inputs

Comment: But does this mean that there is no generic way to target the counter? What if I have 10 input fields; I have to write the code 10 times? That can't be right?

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect.  $('input') returns an array of all input fields, not just the first one.

Comment: Yeah, thought so @DanielBeck. I tried to be as generic as possible, so I even targeted classnames instead of ID's, but can't get it to work as I want to